# Incorrect syntax when working with a variable in IDENTITY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, ddl

I'm trying to create a new table with a primary key value that is a continuation of a previous table.

My code is:

```
DECLARE @Table1_NextKey INT

SELECT @Table1_NextKey = MAX(id) + 1 
FROM [Copy of Table1]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table1
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(@Table1_NextKey, 1) 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [PLAN] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
> Incorrect syntax near '@Table1_NextKey'

Is there a way to get the `Create Table` to work with the variable?

Comment: You can't use a variable in a DDL statement. If you want to do that you need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use literal values for `identity`, you'll need to dynamically construct your `create` statement, as follows

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=Concat(N'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table1(
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(', @Table1_NextKey, N', 1) CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  [PLAN] [nvarchar](255) NULL) 
ON [PRIMARY]')

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks.  One minor change:  The variable needs to be converted to a varchar.  I'll post what I got to work below.

Comment: My apologies, you are using the concat command.  You are correct, your code works.

Comment: no worries yes `concat` always returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

**You are going about this the wrong way.**

What you are clearly trying to do, is copy a table and then you would like to continue the identity values.

In this case, do not *declare* the seed value differently in the `CREATE TABLE`, just manually set it afterwards:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table1
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [PLAN] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Do some copying code here

DECLARE @Table1_NextKey INT =
(
    SELECT @Table1_NextKey = MAX(id)  -- not + 1 
    FROM Table1
);

DBCC CHECKIDENT (Table1 RESEED, @Table1_NextKey) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why SQL Server is so weird about this but with Stu's help, I got this to work:

```
DECLARE @Table1_NextKey INT,
@SQL_command varchar(4000)
select @Table1_NextKey=max(id)+1 from [Copy of Table1]

set @SQL_command=
'CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table1(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(' + convert(varchar(5), @Table1_Nextkey) + ', 1) CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [PLAN] [nvarchar](255) NULL) 
ON [PRIMARY] 
GO'
```

Comment: Whats weird about it?

Comment: `GO` is not an SQL statement, it's a batch separator for SSMS, and will not work with `sp_executesql`